# Getting the desired pattern with triple dots

Tags: javascript

I want to have such a pattern like this as output:

```
"I was sent ... to protect you."
```

Not one space before and another after triple dots. I want to always get this pattern no matter if we have each of these inputs:

> "I was sent... to protect you."
>
> "I was sent ...to protect you."
>
> "I was sent...to protect you."

I used `replace` three times to achieve this but it seems ugly. is there a smarter solution I have to learn?

Note: if we haven't any triple dots we don't want to change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using replace is still the best approach, however you probably should update your condition so that just a single replace is enough.

```js
const regexp = /\s?\.\.\.\s?/;

const text1="I was sent... to protect you."
const text2="I was sent ...to protect you."
const text3="I was sent...to protect you."

console.log(text1.replace(regexp, " ... "))
console.log(text2.replace(regexp, " ... "))
console.log(text3.replace(regexp, " ... "))
```

- `\.` matches a `.` character
- `\s` matches a white space character
- `?` makes the white space character match optional

so the regex will match any of the following `...`,  `...` or `...`  and replace them with `...`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression to group the three consecutive dots `(\.{3})` which is surrounded by 0 or more white-space characters (`\s*`). You can then replace this with the grouped dots surrounded by a space on either side (`' $1 '`).

```js
const dotify = str => str.replace(/\s*(\.{3})\s*/g, ' $1 ');
console.log(dotify("I was sent... to protect you.")); // I was sent ... to protect you.
console.log(dotify("I was sent ...to protect you.")); // I was sent ... to protect you.
console.log(dotify("I was sent...to protect you.")); // I was sent ... to protect you.
console.log(dotify("I was sent ... to protect you.")); // I was sent ... to protect you.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- `.split()` `I was sent... to protect you.` --> `["I was sent", " to protect you.]`
- `.trim()` `["I was sent", " to protect you.]` --> `["I was sent", "to protect you"]`
- `join()` `["I was sent", "to protect you"]` --> `I was sent ... to protect you`

```js
let str = "I was sent... to protect you.";
let str2 = "I was sent...to protect you.";
let str3 = "I was sent ...to protect you.";
let str4 = "I was sent to protect you.";
let str5 = "I was sent             ...                          to protect you.";

function formatText(txt) {
   return txt.split("...").map(el => el.trim()).join(" ... ");
}

console.log(formatText(str));
console.log(formatText(str2));
console.log(formatText(str3));
console.log(formatText(str4));
console.log(formatText(str5));
```